# How to write a trigger to get before and after values in a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two tables `transcriptTable` and `trancript_log`.
I need to get before and after values in `trancriptTable_log` (OldValue,New,Value) when any update accrue on `transcriptTable`.

I have a trigger for before and after update but only one trigger at a time is executed.

Comment: And the code you used would be...

Answer (score 0):

1. Create trancriptTable_log table with required columns
2. create trigger below (one trigger is enough)

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER INSERTEDAndDELETEDTableExample
> ON transcriptTable
> FOR  UPDATE
> AS
> BEGIN
> --to get the old value (insert statement may vary depend on your need and table)
> insert into trancriptTable_log (column_1) SELECT <your_column_name> FROM DELETED
> --to get the new value
> insert into trancriptTable_log values (column_2) SELECT <your_column_name> FROM INSERTED
> END
> ```

Comment: thanks it works but it insert old values in a row and new values in 2nd row.i   want to have old and new values in a single row like "OldValue,New Value".

Comment: Include a where clause so that it will insert in the same row